# What is the difference between appending and assigning value to list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

When I use one-line-for loop in Python, I will got two different values depending on the process I choose(Assign and append processes). I want to understand the difference and how they work.
In the following two examples, I trying to write a program that returns a list that contains only the elements that are common between the lists (without duplicates).

First program with append and I get the right result:

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]

def common_in_two_lists(list1, list2):
   re_list = []
   [re_list.append(val1) for val1 in list1 for val2 in list2 if val1==val2 and val1 not in re_list]
   return re_list
```

After call the function and print output list:

```
l = common_in_two_lists(a, b)
print(l)
```

and the output is:

```
[1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]
```

But when I use assign way as the following I will got the wrong answer:

```
def common_in_two_lists(list1, list2):
   re_list = []
   re_list = [val1 for val1 in list1 for val2 in list2 if val1==val2 and val1 not in re_list]
   return re_list

l = common_in_two_lists(a, b)
print(l)
```

and the output is:

```
[1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]
```

Anyone can learn me to understand How do this two different way work?

Comment: Abusing list comprehensions for a side effect is  a big no-no (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753597/is-it-pythonic-to-use-list-comprehensions-for-just-side-effects). Also, in your second example, `re_list = []` is not necessary since the next line creates a new list any way. `re_list = [val1 for val1 in list1 for val2 in list2 if val1 == val2]` will have the exact same output.

Comment: In the first case you alter the list with each loop. When you reach the second `1` there is already a `1` in `re_list`.

Comment: You should probably study this: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: *I trying to write a program that returns a list that contains only the elements that are common between the lists (without duplicates)*... you should take a look at `set`s... eg: `list(set(a).intersection(b))`...

Comment: @DeepSpace In second example, if I remove the line: `re_list = []` I will get NameError.

Comment: @JonClements This should be the correct (and most elegant) answer

Comment: @JosephSh Becuase you should also delete the `if` condition like I showed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to break down the code into simpler form to understand it.
Taking the first example.

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]


def common_in_two_lists1(list1, list2):
    re_list = []
    for val1 in list1:
        for val2 in list2:
            if val1 == val2 and val1 not in re_list:
                re_list.append(val1)
                print(re_list)
    return re_list


l = common_in_two_lists1(a, b)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 5, 8]
[1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]
```

You can see that the `re_list` is appending the value every time. And the `[]` you have put for the first example is useless.

Coming to your second example. If you check the type of the expression, you would find it to be generator.

```
re_list = print(type(val1 for val1 in list1 for val2 in list2 if val1 == val2 and val1 not in re_list))
<class 'generator'>
```

And generator expression is evaluated only when you are try to fetch the value, that explains why you are getting the duplicate 1 on this code. Because in the expression `re_list` is empty when the generator is created.

Finally coming to your solution:

**I trying to write a program that returns a list that contains only the elements that are common between the lists (without duplicates).**

You should follow  Jon Clements♦ advice and implement it using a set

> you should take a look at sets... eg: list(set(a).intersection(b))

Comment: But I still get NameError if remove the useless `re_list = []` from my first example, Why?

Comment: @JosephSh `re_list = []` is not useless, it is very much required as it is required for declaration. You cannot append on a list until you have it declared.

Comment: `And the [] you have put for the first example is useless.` What I meant by this is the one-liner is having `[]` this become important for the syntax as you are using list comprehension syntax, but overall it is pretty much useless. And you should try to write it in a broken format as what I have done.

Answer (score 2):

In your second example re_list is empty by the time new list is created, so `val1 not in re_list` is always false. In the first one you create a list of what is returned by `re_list.append()` (`None`, as I remember) and assign it to nowhere while modifying `re_list`.

By the way, why don't you use `set()` to obtain a list of unique elements?

Comment: How we can use `set()` to obtain a list of unique elements?

Answer (score 1):

```
def common_in_two_lists(list1, list2):
   re_list = []
   [re_list.append(val1) for val1 in list1 for val2 in list2 if val1==val2 and val1 not in re_list]
   return re_list
```

is equivalent to:

```
def common_in_two_lists(list1, list2):
   re_list = []
   for val1 in list1:
       for val2 in list2:
          if val1==val2 and val1 not in re_list:
             re_list.append(val1)
   return re_list
```

while the second method:

```
def common_in_two_lists(list1, list2):
   re_list = []
   re_list = [val1 for val1 in list1 for val2 in list2 if val1==val2 and val1 not in re_list]
   return re_list
```

is equivalent to

```
def common_in_two_lists(list1, list2):
    re_list_old = []
    re_list = []
    for val1 in list1:
        for val2 in list2:
            if val1==val2 and val1 not in re_list_old: #note re_list_old here
                re_list.append(val1)
    return re_list
```

It is worth to notice that with the *second method you are not checking for duplicates in the final list* because everytime you check the empty list while doing `val1 not in re_list`

Both ways work in `O(n**2)` time complexity, using sets :

```
l = list(set(a) & set(b))
```

it's more efficient and simpler as you can do it with average time complexity `O(min(len(a), len(b))` (the [worst case](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity#set) is `O(len(a)*len(b))`).